# Best way to name methods that returns list of objects

Tags: java, api, methods

I have a class named `ActivityLog`. This class holds a list of `ActivityRecords`. I want to return a list of `ActivityRecords` by these criterias: Environment and Condition. Should the method name include the "criteria"? See example:

```
activityLog.allRecords();
activityLog.allRecordsBy(Environment environment);
activityLog.allRecordsBy(Condition condition);
activityLog.allRecordsBy(Condition condition, Environment environment);
```

or

```
activityLog.allRecordsByEnvironment(Environment environment);
activityLog.allRecordsByCondtion(Condition condition);
```

I probably think the first is better because you will read the method name and you will understand from the parameter what it does, but I may be wrong? Which is the best, or are there even better alternatives?

I could have named the methods `records()`, `recordsBy` etc. too, but I want to have a consitency through my API where you always start writing `all` for lists of objects so you get help from for example Intelli Sense.

Comment: I would go for second approach. You would avoid problem with method overloading. Or `allRecordsBy(Filter)`.

Comment: What would be the problem of overloading?

Comment: Both variants are good. As above said, if you add overlapping arguments a named approach would be better.

Comment: @Bob if you are programming against interfaces (i.e. Environment, Condition are interfaces), you will have problem when a class implement both interface. Plus it is harder to read the code.

Comment: Ah, that is true. Have not thought about that before but that makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like putting the criteria in the actual method name.  So I would use:

> activityLog.allRecordsByEnvironment(Environment environment);

To me proper method naming expresses a small summary of what the method does.  Since the parameters are included in the method signature I would not consider the parameters to be part of the actual name, therefore not placing the criteria in the name gives the user of an api incomplete information about the methods functionality.  (IMO)

I applaud your effort to practice self documenting code, great practice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd treat it the same as `static factory methods`, which are **named constructors**. And there not only parameter says what this method does, its name itself does it. So I'd choose 2nd option.

@Bob, about names being too long - even if you would put 2 parameters into its name, it still would be ok for me. Anyway you should avoid having methods with more than 3 parameters. Following this rule will prevent your methods' names from being enormous long.

Comment: So you don't think the name is to long?

Comment: A method name should convey meaning.  If it requires a few extra characters to do that I feel its ok.  I get frustrated when I see method names kept intentionally short just to save a few keystrokes.  These names deviate from the main goal of a method name, which is to tell you what the heck the method does.  If your to lazy to press a few extra keys, you have bigger problems than the method name.

Comment: @Bob I wasn't calling you lazy.  I have just had experiences where developers have completely misrepresented the named of a method because it was easy to type.  For example one piece of code I looked at had a method named nice().  It ran some js that added styling to certain elements.  How are you supposed to know what nice() actually does by looking at a method call, especially in JS where intellisense is lacking in most ides

Comment: That is not particular readable. Okey, I will make the method names complete but would you name it getRecords... or allRecords...?

Comment: @Bob I'd use `get` prefix. Because what you do is getting records. *all* can mean realy *anything* - for example "append argument to all records and return them".

Comment: @dantuch I like the prefix "find" for methods that are used to query a db and return some set of objects.  I stay away from prefixing these methods with "get" because the prefix may get confused as a simple accessor statement when there is actually more functionality behind the method

Answer (score 1):

I like the overloaded variant (your first example), because it communicates that the methods are all related and provide largely the same functionality, aka, you are returning records, filtered by some criteria. You will see examples of this in many open source libraries and even the SDK itself.

Answer (score 0):

Methods in `OOP` represent behavior, so I would name all of them `getRecords()` and made them overloaded.

In my opinion, specifying criteria in the name of method looks like naming heirarchy classes like this

```
Car -> BMW_Car -> X5_BMW_Car
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take the first one.

If these methods are doing the same thing or providing the same functionality then they should have the same name. But be aware of Effective Java Item 41 and 42. You've to ensure that at least one corresponding param of overloaded method are having radically different types.

The 2nd approach becomes ugly very fast with every param added. I see this in often in Broker classes at work. There are people writing methods like `findByFirstnameAndLastnameAndBirthdayOrderByUgliness(blablub)`. No comment.

Comment: You guys are making it hard for me to choose:)

Comment: Well, I hoped this one makes it more easy to choose. :)

Comment: I see the benefits of both approaches, can't choose, ah life is hard!

Comment: Btw that what @user802421 said in his comment is what is meant by radically different types. Or when they are not radically different then it must not have to matter which overloaded method is executed. In fact this should be true when you name them the same.